# animation hover from top

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I am using the Category Grid View Gallery on my plugin site and I was wondering how I can change the hover animation to start from the top rather than the bottom of the thumbnail:

http://www.itsalifestylething.co.uk/travel/

cgview.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // To remove the css class for CSS fallback strategy
    $("div.cgview ul li div").removeClass("cgnojs");


  $("div.cgview li").mouseenter(function(){
    var d = this.getElementsByTagName("div");
    if($(d[0]).attr('class')=='cgback hover'){
        $(d[0]).stop(true,true).animate({height: '100%'},700);
        $(d[1]).stop(true,true).animate({height: '50%'},700);
    }
    });
  $("div.cgview li").mouseleave(function(){
    var d = this.getElementsByTagName("div");
    if($(d[0]).attr('class')=='cgback hover'){
        $(d[0]).stop(true,true).animate({height: '0px'},700);
        $(d[1]).stop(true,true).animate({height: '0px'},700);
    }

    });
  /*Events for colorbox (Fix for small popup window in colorbox due to delay in load of images*/
  $(".cgpost").colorbox({onComplete:function(){$.colorbox.resize();}});  

  /* Pagination */
  $(document).ready(function(){
        if(paginateVal){
         $('ul#cg-ul').easyPaginate({
            step:paginateVal,
            nextprev:false,
            controls:'cg-page-controls'
      });
      }
                             });

});
```

CSS

```
div.cgview{
    list-style-type: none; 
    clear:both;
    text-align:center;
}

div.cgview ul{
    margin-left:-10px;
    list-style-type: none; 
    clear:both;
    overflow:hidden;
}


div.cgview ul li{font-weight:bold;text-align:center;margin:10px 0 0 10px;
                    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;-moz-border-radius: 10px;border-radius: 10px;
                }
div.cgview ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    border:4px double;
    overflow:hidden;

}

div.cgview ul li:hover {border:4px solid;}
div.cgview ul li div.cgtitle{height:0%;overflow:hidden;z-index:3;position:absolute;bottom:0;left:0;width:inherit;}
div.cgview ul li div.cgtitle p{width:inherit;}
div.cgview ul li div.cgback{
                    height:0%;overflow:hidden;z-index:2;position:absolute;bottom:0;left:0;width:inherit;
                    filter:alpha(opacity=60);
                    opacity:0.6;
}
div.cgview ul li div.cgtitle p a{font-family:Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;text-decoration:none;}

/* Light Theme */
div.cgview.light ul li{border-color: #aaa;}
div.cgview.light ul li:hover{border-color: #ccc;}
div.cgview.light ul li div.cgback{background-color:#fff;}
div.cgview.light ul li div.cgtitle p a{color:#000;}

/* Dark Theme */
div.cgview.dark ul li{border-color: #777;}
div.cgview.dark ul li:hover{border-color: #555;}
div.cgview.dark ul li div.cgback{background-color:#000;}
div.cgview.dark ul li div.cgtitle p a{color:#fff;}


/* CSS hover Fallback Strategy : In a case when Javascript is not loaded/disabled,
    the plugin falls back to a pure css hover effect. */


div.cgview ul li div.cgback.cgnojs.hover, div.cgview ul li div.cgback.cgnojs.never{
    display:none;
    height:35%;
}
div.cgview ul li div.cgtitle.cgnojs.hover, div.cgview ul li div.cgtitle.cgnojs.never{
    display:none;
    height:32%;
}
div.cgview ul li div.cgback.always{
    display:block;
    height:35%;
}
div.cgview ul li div.cgtitle.always{
    display:block;
    height:32%;
}
div.cgview ul li:hover > div.cgback.cgnojs.hover, div.cgview ul li:hover > div.cgtitle.cgnojs.hover{
    display: block;
}

div#cg-credits{font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:80%;color:#777; text-align:right;}
div#cg-credits a{color: #3366CC; text-decoration:none;}
/*Pagination Controls style */
ol#cg-page-controls{clear:both;position:relative;margin:0 0 0 -2px;}
    ol#cg-page-controls li{
        display:inline-block;
        position:relative;
        width:16px;
        height:16px;
        background:url(images/bg_buttons.png) no-repeat 0 0;
        text-indent:-8000px;
        list-style:none;
        cursor:pointer;
        margin:0 2px;
        }
    ol#cg-page-controls li:hover{background:url(images/bg_buttons.png) no-repeat 0 -16px;}
    ol#cg-page-controls li.current{color:#f00;font-weight:bold;background:url(images/bg_buttons.png) no-repeat 0 -32px;}
    /*ol#cg-page-controls li.prev, ol#cg-page-controls li.next{     }*/
    ol#cg-page-controls li.prev{background:url(images/bg_buttons.png) no-repeat 0 -64px;}
    ol#cg-page-controls li.next{background:url(images/bg_buttons.png) no-repeat 0 -48px;}


/*
    ColorBox Core Style:
    The following CSS is consistent between example themes and should not be altered.
*/
#colorbox, #cboxOverlay, #cboxWrapper{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:9999; overflow:hidden;}
#cboxOverlay{position:fixed; width:100%; height:100%;}
#cboxMiddleLeft, #cboxBottomLeft{clear:left;}
#cboxContent{position:relative;}
#cboxLoadedContent{overflow:auto;}
#cboxTitle{margin:0;}
#cboxLoadingOverlay, #cboxLoadingGraphic{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%;}
#cboxPrevious, #cboxNext, #cboxClose, #cboxSlideshow{cursor:pointer;}
.cboxPhoto{float:left; margin:auto; border:0; display:block;}
.cboxIframe{width:100%; height:100%; display:block; border:0;}

/*  User Style:
    Change the following styles to modify the appearance of ColorBox.
*/
#cboxOverlay{background:#fff;}
#colorbox{}
    #cboxTopLeft{width:25px; height:25px; background:url(images/border1.png) no-repeat 0 0;}
    #cboxTopCenter{height:25px; background:url(images/border1.png) repeat-x 0 -50px;}
    #cboxTopRight{width:25px; height:25px; background:url(images/border1.png) no-repeat -25px 0;}
    #cboxBottomLeft{width:25px; height:25px; background:url(images/border1.png) no-repeat 0 -25px;}
    #cboxBottomCenter{height:25px; background:url(images/border1.png) repeat-x 0 -75px;}
    #cboxBottomRight{width:25px; height:25px; background:url(images/border1.png) no-repeat -25px -25px;}
    #cboxMiddleLeft{width:25px; background:url(images/border2.png) repeat-y 0 0;}
    #cboxMiddleRight{width:25px; background:url(images/border2.png) repeat-y -25px 0;}
    #cboxContent{background:#fff; overflow:hidden;}
        #cboxError{padding:50px; border:1px solid #ccc;}
        #cboxLoadedContent{margin-bottom:20px;}
        #cboxTitle{position:absolute; bottom:0px; left:0; text-align:center; width:100%; color:#999;}
        #cboxCurrent{position:absolute; bottom:0px; left:100px; color:#999;}
        #cboxSlideshow{position:absolute; bottom:0px; right:42px; color:#444;}
        #cboxPrevious{position:absolute; bottom:0px; left:0; color:#444;}
        #cboxNext{position:absolute; bottom:0px; left:63px; color:#444;}
        #cboxLoadingOverlay{background:#fff url(images/loading.gif) no-repeat center center;}
        #cboxClose{position:absolute; top:0; right:0; display:block; color:#333; font-weight:bold; font-size:16px; padding-right:5px;font-family: Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

/*
  The following fixes a problem where IE7 and IE8 replace a PNG's alpha transparency with a black fill
  when an alpha filter (opacity change) is set on the element or ancestor element.  This style is not applied to IE9.
*/
.cboxIE #cboxTopLeft,
.cboxIE #cboxTopCenter,
.cboxIE #cboxTopRight,
.cboxIE #cboxBottomLeft,
.cboxIE #cboxBottomCenter,
.cboxIE #cboxBottomRight,
.cboxIE #cboxMiddleLeft,
.cboxIE #cboxMiddleRight {
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00FFFFFF,endColorstr=#00FFFFFF);
}

/*
  The following provides PNG transparency support for IE6
*/
.cboxIE6 #cboxTopLeft{background:url(images/ie6/borderTopLeft.png);}
.cboxIE6 #cboxTopCenter{background:url(images/ie6/borderTopCenter.png);}
.cboxIE6 #cboxTopRight{background:url(images/ie6/borderTopRight.png);}
.cboxIE6 #cboxBottomLeft{background:url(images/ie6/borderBottomLeft.png);}
.cboxIE6 #cboxBottomCenter{background:url(images/ie6/borderBottomCenter.png);}
.cboxIE6 #cboxBottomRight{background:url(images/ie6/borderBottomRight.png);}
.cboxIE6 #cboxMiddleLeft{background:url(images/ie6/borderMiddleLeft.png);}
.cboxIE6 #cboxMiddleRight{background:url(images/ie6/borderMiddleRight.png);}

.cboxIE6 #cboxTopLeft,
.cboxIE6 #cboxTopCenter,
.cboxIE6 #cboxTopRight,
.cboxIE6 #cboxBottomLeft,
.cboxIE6 #cboxBottomCenter,
.cboxIE6 #cboxBottomRight,
.cboxIE6 #cboxMiddleLeft,
.cboxIE6 #cboxMiddleRight {
    _behavior: expression(this.src = this.src ? this.src : this.currentStyle.backgroundImage.split('"')[1], this.style.background = "none", this.style.filter = "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src=" + this.src + ", sizingMethod='scale')");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here in your css change `bottom:0px` for `top:0px`

```
div.cgview ul li div.cgback{
    height:0%;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index:2;
    position:absolute;
    top:0; /*here the change*/
    left:0;
    width:inherit;
    filter:alpha(opacity=60);
    opacity:0.6;
}
```

For the text make the same change in the class`.cgtitle` from `bottom` to `top` And for the `p` tag inside this add this CSS:

```
div.cgview ul li div.cgtitle p {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the text is still coming from the bottom.